# Generic trigger on update / delete to backup current row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

My situation is this:

- I have a table, call it `x`.
- Every time a row is updated or deleted, a copy of the old row should be inserted into `x_history`.
- Additionally `x_history` will have its' own auto-incrementing id column, call that `histid`.
- It is very important to have its' own id column as this will give us the flexibility to build version restore functionality.

I have 100+ tables to apply this to so I'm looking for a generic trigger that can be used for any table to backup one row into a history table. Only the 2 table names should vary from trigger to trigger. Specifying all column names is really not what I'm looking for.

I need to do this in MySQL but have added MSSQL too - I know both so can convert between one and the other easy enough.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, Triggers are not the optimal solution for such purposes.
If possible, you might want to consider changing your database design.
Normally, a better way to handle such things are keeping the hole history in the source table, And have a status column that tells you for each row if it's deleted, updated, or current.

I have little to no experience with MySql, but I have been working with Sql server for the past 7 or 8 years, so what I'm about to say is true for sql server, but may be different for MySql.

If you choose to go with the triggers approach, keep in mind that after update triggers will execute even if the update does not change the row data (e.g update tableName set col1 = 1 where idCol = 4, the update trigger will be executed even if the col1 value before the update was 1, so no data was changed.)

For SqlServer, you might want to consider a common history table, that has only 6 columns:
 1. Identity column
 2. Table name column
 3. Row Id column (original id from the original table)
 4. Row Status column (e.g updated, deleted)
 5. Action date (the date the row was copied to the history table)
 6. Row content column (this should be an XML datatype (not sure if MySql has such dataType))

and then all you have to do is to use "SELECT * FROM deleted/inserted FOR XML AUTO" to create the content for the 6th. column.

Comment: Thanks Zohar - we'll certainly consider this but in the meantime I have decided to restructure the DB in any case - will take a while to get back to where I was.

Comment: Well, if you restructure the database I would recommend the "never delete, never update" approach, unless you have a volume of records that is larger then your storage capabilities. Also, I don't know if MySql has that feature, but in Sql Server you can add a where clause to your indexes, so that the history part of the table will have little to no effect when using the indexes.

Comment: Nice concept please provide more details or a link to some further reading about it, thanks.

Comment: @Ice: I'm not sure what concept would you like to read more about. In any case I have no links to provide for any of them. the "never delete, never update" concept I've mentioned is actually a recommendation I've got from an MSSQL DBA that was consulting the company I've worked for at the time, the other solutions using triggers is kind of a self-development and I'm not sure I can explain it any better then I've already did in my Answer. If you have specific questions I guess I can try to answer them.

Comment: @Zohar, thanks for your answer. one thing is some kind of tricky: how to restore backuped rows - in best case with a generic procedure...